# Consecutive downloads to browser in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this common method to download a file in javascript:

```
var URI = //some uri
var dl = document.createElement('a');
    dl.href = URI;

dl.download = 'file name';       
document.body.appendChild(dl);
download_link.click();
document.body.removeChild(dl);
```

When I execute it the first time it works, but fails for the next downloads. Do you know why this is? Thanks

Comment: This is probably because the browser only allows one download per human interaction. If that's the problem, then the only solution is to have the user click multiple times, once per download.

Comment: "_but fails_" doesn't really tell us much. What is the error you get? Or result?

Comment: Without removing the anchor tag from the dom, check if you are manually able to download the file by clicking the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to run your code for the second time, Chrome shows this message:
[image: Request to download file]

My browser is in pt-BR, the translation is as follows:

> http://stackoverflow.com would like to:
>   * Download multiple files
>   [Allow] [Block]

If you block it, it will not download the next files. You can check your current permission settings by click in the (i) icon before the URL and looking for automatic downloads. The default only downloads once.

Comment: Thanks. I realized it was due to the chrome permissions after.